# What edition(s) of wubi input method do the various wubi packages in Ubuntu implement?

Tags: input-method, chinese

I'm talking about packages that provide the wubi (五筆) input method for the Chinese language, not the "Windows-based Ubuntu Installer".

I see that there are at least these packages that provide the wubi input method:

- `fcitx-table-wubi`
- `fcitx-table-wubi-large`
- `ibus-table-wubi`

There are 3 editions of the wubi input method, according to the inventor, Wang Yongmin's website:

- '86 edition
- '98 edition
- New Century edition (新世紀版), a.k.a. Grand Unified edition (大一統版) because it's the edition that *officially* supports the input of both simplified and traditional Chinese characters.

What edition(s) are implemented by those various packages? For context, I'm mostly interested in the package versions in either Ubuntu 18.04 or 20.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As regards `ibus-table-wubi` the `README` file states that it's Wubi-Heifeng86.

https://salsa.debian.org/input-method-team/ibus-table-chinese/-/blob/master/README

Take it as a hint how you can find out for the Fcitx packages.